# How to save multiple checkbox Label Text into database in Laravel

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, checkbox, label

I'm trying to save multiple Label Text of Checkboxes.
First, I'm saving chechbox value in a column of database table. But other than that, I have to save Label of each those checkbox checked in another column of table.

My table:

```
 Schema::create('restaurant_offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
              .......
                $table->string('additionalOptions')->nullable();
                $table->string('additionalOptionsSum')->nullable();
                ......
            });
```

My blade:

```
<label class="form-check-label" for="additionalOptionsSum" >
    <input class="form-check-input calc" type="checkbox" id="additionalOptionsSum" name="additionalOptionsSum[]" value="19"> Delivery System 
    </label>
<label class="form-check-label" for="additionalOptionsSum" >
    <input class="form-check-input calc" type="checkbox" id="additionalOptionsSum" name="additionalOptionsSum[]" value="29"> Takeaway System 
    </label>
<label class="form-check-label" for="additionalOptionsSum" >
    <input class="form-check-input calc" type="checkbox" id="additionalOptionsSum" name="additionalOptionsSum[]" value="39"> Table Reservation System 
    </label>
```

My Controller:

```
$data = new RestaurantOffer;

         ......
         $data["additionalOptionsSum"] = implode(",", $request->get("additionalOptionsSum"));
         $data["additionalOptions"] = implode(',', $request->get("aditionaloptions"));
```

So, I have to save values and labels text of each checkbox checked as array in database.
Values of additionalOptionsSum is working well.
Now, I have to save additionalOptions too.

Example, if I check two checkboxes, the table in database, should be like this:

```
id| additionalOptions| additionalOptionsSum|
-----------------------------
1 | Delivery System, | 19, 29|
    Takeaway System
```

For the moment it is looking like this:

```
id| additionalOptions| additionalOptionsSum|
    -----------------------------
    1 |              | 19, 29|
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well... labels are not posted. you will have to convert the value to the label text in the backend.

Comment: Thank you Gert, could you pleas help me how can I convert the checkbox values to label text?